# IntegerField subtraction in Django

Tags: django, django-models

In this template ,I try to subtract two Integer Fields .

post_update.html

```
{% load mathfilters %}
<html>
<p> {{ post.wallet|sub:post.cost }}</p>
<p> {{ post.wallet }}</p>
</html>
```

However, I'm getting

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /update/
Failed lookup for key [post] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}]
Failed lookup for key [%s] in %r.
```

models.py:

```
cost = models.IntegerField(default=0)
wallet = models.IntegerField(default=5000)
```

With my modest level of understanding , I'm not able to catch the error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please show your models. Possibly `wallet` or `cost` doesn't exists in `post`. Also, you mey consider looking on [custome template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) for your needs.

Comment: Next thing - add full error stack trace. `VariableDoesNotExist at` should continue with where exception occured. Another guess - is that possible that `post` is `None`?